How to split a (sysrepo, netconf) xpath into a json object
I am working with NETCONF and Sysrepo. When a change is made in the sysrepo managed configuration, it gives a call back so that the corresponding change can be effected in the underlying hardware. The call back has an xpath parameter which gives the exact location in the yang model where the data has been changed. Some examples are as follows:

/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface[name='mgmt7']/ietf-ip:ipv4/mtu
/ietf-interfaces:interfaces/interface[name='mgmt7']/ietf-ip:ipv4/address[ip='192.168.1.15']/prefix-length
/ietf-routing:routing/control-plane-protocols/control-plane-protocol[type='ietf-routing:static'][name='static']/static-routes/ietf-ipv4-unicast-routing:ipv4/route[destination-prefix='17.0.0.0/8']/destination-prefix

Now to processes this I have a requirement to parse this and split into components. For example the first item may be split into a json format as follows:
{
    "class": "ietf-interfaces",
    "path": "interfaces/interface",
    "item": "mgmt7",
    "subtree": {
        "class": "ietf-ip",
        "path": "ipv4/mtu"
    }
}

I have searched but could not find any library which can parse or split an xpath. Most libraries are used to use an xpath to locate a data in an xml file.
What would be a good approach to parse the xpath into some thing like I have described above?
Thanks!

"Most libraries are used to use an xpath to locate a data in an xml file." -- that's what xpath is for. It's not really clear what you're trying to do or why you think the first example should parse into that particular JSON structure.

Have you really used a search engine? First hit, DOC.

@Hermann12 I am already using Netconf client, this requirement happens after a change in made by the Netconf client and Sysrepo makes a call back.

@larsks Thats a long story. Yes, I understand that xpath is for locating items in XML document. But in my scenario I need to use the xpath to lookup an object hierarchy so that the changes referred by the xpath can be effected.

Find a parser generator that is fed a language grammar (XPath 1.0 in your case) and is able to generate a parse tree from input, which you then transform into desired output. PLY (Python Lex-Yacc) could be what you need - not sure, because I've not used it. My go-to generator is ANTLR4, which doesn't do Python (I think).
